# Is the integral with respect to increasing continuous functions the limit of integrals with respect to $C^1$ functions?

Tags: integration, analysis

if $\xi$ is continuous increasing can we find $\xi^n\in C^1$  such that $$\int_0^t f(u)\, d\xi = \lim_n\int_0^t f(u)\, d\xi^n$$

for every continuous $f$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the integral need not even *exist* for *every* continuous $f$. If, say, we restrict to continuous $f$ with compact support, then yes we can find such $\xi^n$.

For example, say $\phi\ge0$ is smooth, has compact support, and $\int\phi=1$. Define $\phi_n(t)=n\phi(nt)$, and now define $\xi^n$ as the convolution $$\xi^n=\xi*\phi_n.$$